# snakemake - replacing wildcards in input directive by anonymous function

Tags: python-3.x, snakemake

I am writing a snakemake that will run a bioinformatics pipeline for several input samples. These input files (two for each analysis, one with the partial string match `R1` and the second with the partial string match `R2`) start with a pattern and end with the extension `.fastq.gz`. Eventually I want to perform multiple operations, though, for this example I just want to align the fastq reads against a reference genome using [bwa mem](http://bio-bwa.sourceforge.net/bwa.shtml). So for this example my input file is `NIPT-N2002394-LL_S19_R1_001.fastq.gz` and I want to generate `NIPT-N2002394-LL.bam` (see code below specifying the directories where input and output are).

My `config.yaml` file looks like so:

```
# Run_ID
run: "200311_A00154_0454_AHHHKMDRXX"

# Base directory: the analysis directory from which I will fetch the samples
bd: "/nexusb/nipt/"


# Define the prefix
# will be used to subset the folders in bd
prefix: "NIPT"

# Reference:
ref: "/nexus/bhinckel/19/ONT_projects/PGD_breakpoint/ref_hg19_local/hg19_chr1-y.fasta"
```

And below is my snakefile

```
import os
import re
#############
# config file
#############
configfile: "config.yaml"


#######################################
# Parsing variables from config.yaml
#######################################
RUN = config['run']

BD = config['bd']

PREFIX = config['prefix']

FQDIR = f'/nexusb/Novaseq/{RUN}/Unaligned/'

BASEDIR = BD + RUN
SAMPLES = [sample for sample in os.listdir(BASEDIR) if sample.startswith(PREFIX)]
# explanation: in BASEDIR I have multiple subdirectories. The names of the subdirectories starting with PREFIX will be the name of the elements I want to have in the list SAMPLES, which eventually shall be my {sample} wildcard

#############
# RULES
#############
rule all:
    input:
        expand("aligned/{sample}.bam", sample = SAMPLES)


rule bwa_map:
    input:
        REF = config['ref'],
        R1 = FQDIR + "{sample}_S{s}_R1_001.fastq.gz",
        R2 = FQDIR + "{sample}_S{s}_R2_001.fastq.gz"
    output:
        "aligned/{sample}.bam"
    shell:
        "bwa mem {input.REF} {input.R1} {input.R2}| samtools view -Sb - > {output}"
```

But I am getting:

```
Building DAG of jobs...
WildcardError in line 55 of /nexusb/nipt/200311_A00154_0454_AHHHKMDRXX/testMetrics/snakemake/Snakefile:
Wildcards in input files cannot be determined from output files:
's'
```

When calling `snakemake -np`

I believe my error lies in the definitions of `R1` and `R2` in the input directive. I find it puzzling because according to the [official documentation](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#snakefiles-wildcards) snakemake should interpret any wildcard as the regex `.+`. But it is not doing that for sample `NIPT-PearlPPlasma-05-PPx`, whose `R1` and `R2` should be `NIPT-PearlPPlasma-05-PPx_S5_R1_001.fastq.gz` and `NIPT-PearlPPlasma-05-PPx_S5_R2_001.fastq.gz`, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look again at the snakemake tutorial on how input is inferred from output, anyways I think the problem lies in this piece of code:

```
output:
    expand("aligned/{sample}.bam", sample = SAMPLES)
```

And needs to be changed into

```
output:
    "aligned/{sample}.bam"
```

What you had didn't work because before `expand("aligned/{sample}.bam", sample = SAMPLES)` basically becomes a list like this `["aligned/sample0.bam","aligned/sample1.bam"]`. When you remove the expand, you only give a "description" of how the output should look like, and thus snakemake can infer the wildcards and input.

---

edit:

It's difficult to test it since I don't have the actual files, but you should do something like this. Won't work if multiple *S*-thingies exist.

```
def get_reads(wildcards):
    R1 = FQDIR + f"{wildcards.sample}_S{{s}}_R1_001.fastq.gz"
    R2 = FQDIR + f"{wildcards.sample}_S{{s}}_R2_001.fastq.gz"
    globbed = glob_wildcards(R1)
    R1, R2 = expand([R1, R2], s=globbed.s)
    return {"R1": R1, "R2": R2}


rule bwa_map:
    input:
        unpack(get_reads),
        REF = config['ref']
    output:
        "aligned/{sample}.bam"
    shell:
        "bwa mem {input.REF} {input.R1} {input.R2}| samtools view -Sb - > {output}"
```

Comment: yes, my output directive was indeed not correct. I have adapted it according to your suggestion, though still getting the same error, as described in my edited question.

Comment: This returns (for one sample) after calling a dry run: `bwa mem /nexusb/Novaseq/200311_A00154_0454_AHHHKMDRXX/Unaligned/NIPT-PearlPPlasma-15-PP1D_S15_R1_001.fastq.gz /nexusb/Novaseq/200311_A00154_0454_AHHHKMDRXX/Unaligned/NIPT-PearlPPlasma-15-PP1D_S15_R1_001.fastq.gz /nexus/bhinckel/19/ONT_projects/PGD_breakpoint/ref_hg19_local/hg19_chr1-y.fasta | samtools view -Sb - > aligned/NIPT-PearlPPlasma-15-PP1D.bam`. So it is not extracting `R1` and `R2`

Comment: Also `bwa mem` has positional arguments, with `REF` coming first, so if I change the order under the input directive I get `positional argument follows keyword argument`

Comment: @BCArg, I made a typo, I edited it. I don't understand what you mean with the positional arguments, since this is not changing the order of the calls.

Comment: It does work now, thanks very much. I have the impression that the shell directive was `bwa mem` {input} in one of your previous edits, which is a problem as the first argument of bwa mem is `REF`. Would you recommend any tutorial on snakemake? I found the official one too superficial and I am struggling to find a more thorough one.

Comment: @BCArg not really. I think Snakemake just has a steep learning curve :(. Knowing how Python works helps a lot, but I wouldn't recommend learning Python just for Snakemake. And I think the Snakemake docs are quite good, but it can be difficult to find what you are looking for when you don't know how it is called what you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210676/discussion-between-bcarg-and-maarten-vd-sande).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
rule bwa_map:
    input:
        REF = config['ref'],
        R1 = FQDIR + "{sample}_S{s}_R1_001.fastq.gz",
        R2 = FQDIR + "{sample}_S{s}_R2_001.fastq.gz"
    output:
        "aligned/{sample}.bam"
```

Your `output` clearly defines a pattern where `{sample}` is a wildcard. When Snakemake builds the DAG and finds that any other rule requires a file that matches this pattern, it sets a concrete value to the `wildcard.sample`. At this moment all the inputs shall be defined, but you are introducing one more level of indirection: the wildcard `{s}` which is not defined.

The value of `{s}` shall be clearly inferred from the `output`. If you can do it in design time, substitute the it with the concrete values, otherwise you may use `checkpoint` feature of Snakemake.